# Unity UI glitches while loading

Tags: unity, gui

I have the following scene canvas elements:

```
 left panel
     character game object
 right panel
     option panel - vertical layout group, content size fitter
         slider panel - vertical layout group, content size fitter
             input panel - horizontal layout group, content size fitter
                 text
                 slider
             input panel - horizontal layout group, content size fitter
                 text
                 slider
         button
```

After I hit play, the button's Y position is wrong but corrects itself after a brief second. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Here is a gif:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by only having the content size fitter on "option panel" and removing it from all children.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem! Don't forget to [mark this as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/228147) - it helps other people who may encounter similar problems. Good luck with your project!